# nbdev_build_lib error with Anaconda3 and windows

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, fast-ai

I am just experimenting with nbdev and was following the tutorial. https://nbdev.fast.ai/tutorial.html
However when I tried the command `nbdev_build_lib` on the terminal it gives me the following error:

`'nbdev_build_lib' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

I am on Windows10, python 3.6 and Anaconda3. I also did the install with `conda install -c fastai nbdev`.

Has anyone seen this error before? If so how did you solve it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

According to this [github issue on nbdev](https://github.com/fastai/nbdev/issues/436), one possible solution is to install `nbdev` using pip instead of conda.

Comment: Thanks! I did try that, but without much success. However the issue was fixed after switching to python 3.7.